# How to loop through list items in a jquery $.each call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with this AJAX success function, using the $.each method to loop through the data to create the titles, divs and outside ul tags for each list but I cant seem to figure out how to loop through and create list items when I'm already looping through to make containers for the list items. Here is the code I'm currently working with,

```
$(function() {
    var $accordion= $("#accordion");
     $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "PDOconnect.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,data){
                $accordion.append('<p>'+ data.name + '</p>');
                $accordion.append('<div id='+data.name+'><ul></ul></div>');
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
    });// end ajax 
});
```

I understand the `$.each` is already an iteration method, but what if the goal is to create another iteration within an iteration?
how do you create a loop within a loop?

say the desired output was,

```
         <div id="accordion">
            <p> Electrition</p>
            <div>
            <ul>
              <li>jon</li>
              <li>jill</li>         
           </ul>
           </div>

            <p>Engineer</p>
           <div>
            <ul>
              <li>jerry</li>
              <li>laura</li>
           </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
```

and you were getting stdclass objects from the server like so,

```
       array( 
           [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                [id] => 3
                [title] => Electrition
                [img] => 
                [description] => 
                [school] => 
                [location] => 1
                [url] => 
                [tablename] => 3
                [votes] => 0
                [name] => John Doe
                [NumJobsdone] => 4
                  )

               [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Electrition
                    [img] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [school] => 
                    [location] => 1
                    [url] => 
                    [tablename] => 2
                    [votes] => 0
                    [name] => Tico Marinez
                    [NumJobsdone] => 6
                      )

             [3] => stdClass Object
                   (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Engineer
                    [img] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [school] => 
                    [location] => 1
                    [url] => 
                    [tablename] => 2
                    [votes] => 0
                    [name] => Jerry Smity
                    [NumJobsdone] => 6
                       )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                     (
                      [id] => 2
                      [title] => Engineer
                      [img] => 
                      [description] => 
                      [school] => 
                      [location] => 1
                      [url] => 
                      [tablename] => 2
                      [votes] => 0
                      [name] => Laura Bastian
                      [NumJobsdone] => 6
                       )
                       )
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data and describe the output you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: ill edit the post, and add that information

Answer (score 1):

you're probably looking for [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

which allows you return an array of whatever you specify.

```
$("#parnet")
    .append($.map(data, function(el) {
        return $("<div>")
            .append(....)
        ;}
    ));
```

This sort of chaining is what makes jquery so powerful. You can nest loops this way indefinitely, it's how I make tables etc very easily without templates

Comment: what would the output be if i was returning arrays? this is helpful regardless though, as i see where to put a for loop.

Comment: used in this append context, the returned array creates DOM siblings.  For instance <tbody> append [<tr> append [<td> append <div>] ]